# Liquid rotating in a cylindrical vessel

Tags: classical-mechanics, centrifugal-force

T.W.B. Kibble "Classical Mechanics" (1973) gives a few examples of the application of the centrifugal force. One such case is a liquid that is rotating inside a cylindrical vessel. Kibble assumes that the liquid particles all obtain an angular frequency $\omega$. He then chooses this rotating frame, claiming that the liquid is at rest. He then states that there is a centrifugal potential $$V = -\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x^2+y^2).$$ He then adds the graviational potential $V = mgz$ acting on the fluid particles and concludes that the surface of the fluid must be equipotential and therefore a paraboloid of revolution. I have no reason to dispute the correctness of this result.

However I have many question regarding this derivation. In a previous chapter on a planet orbiting a star he claimed that the kinetic energy of the planet can be split into a radial and an angular contribution. The angular term can be rewritten using the (constant) angular momentum. This way the rotational energy becomes a radial term that acts as a repulsive (pseudo) potential. Its derivative is equal to the centrifugal force. If we follow this method, we get the same result here, but without the minus sign. So there is something odd going on.

Furthermore the concept of centrifugal force is introduced to balance a centripetal force. The balance of the two forces results in stability. How does this apply to the rotating liquid system? I don't see a centripetal force at work ! So how can the rotation be stable? Actually I think the externally forced rotation of the fluid induces an outward pressure, which should be taken into account in the description.

It also occurs to me that since the liquid is pushed outwards against the walls of the vessel, a force is present. Which  implies that the vessel walls must generate an equal force in the opposite direction. All these aspects are missing in Kibble's treatment.

===================================================================

Edit. My intuition tells me that in the inertial (laboratory) frame the relevant physical quantities describing the system are:

$T = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x^2+y^2)$ is the kinetic energy of a fluid element.

$V = mgz +\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x^2+y^2)$ is the potential energy of a fluid element; the second term is the potential energy of the centripetal force required to enable the rotation.

$J$. There is an angular moment present due to the rotation of the fluid, but since the angular frequency remains constant $J$ does not play a role in the calculation of the shape of the fluid surface.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a free body diagram?

Comment: seems like you are confused with the use of that fictitious thing. You should analyse the same problem using an inertial frame, i.e. no centrifugal. Then you can see how the analysis changes with the rotating frame.